# How to change the background color of BottomSheet in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image: Screenshot]

When I use the showModalBottomSheet method to pop up a bottomSheet, how to make the background color transparent.
because I needed the rounded corners, I knew that changing the canvasColor in the materialApp would do the trick, but other widgets would also change colors.

I tried to embed it in the theme, but it didn't work

```
showModalBottomSheet < Null > (context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.orange),
        child: Material(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0), topRight: Radius.circular(16.0)),
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.purple,
            ),
        ),
    );
});
```

Comment: I think it's working, just that the purple content fills the whole material. Try adding some margin to the Container or don't set a color for the Container.

Comment: I've tried it. If don't set the Container's color,it will fill by orange color that specified by this statement "data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.orange)",but the default white background color is still there

Comment: And adding any margin won't work

Comment: What default white background do you mean? If you set rounded corners, then this is probably the background from behind the material thats visible outside the rounded corners.

Comment: It's a white background cut off by the corners,
Is the canvasColor defined in the theme attribute of the MaterialApp
I can't change the color here

Comment: What I want is to get rid of the white background on two rounded corners on the left and right

Comment: But that comes from behind the material. You need to set the color of the widget behind. You can for example wrap the `Material` in a `Container` and set the color there or whatever is behind the modal bottom sheet.

Comment: You mean only change the background color by adding a container,right?
That's not going to do what I want. I want the corners to be transparent

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just add this in your top level ThemeData. This will solve your problem

`bottomSheetTheme: BottomSheetThemeData(backgroundColor: Colors.black54)`

Comment: `backgroundColor:` should be `Colors.transparent` because the underlying Color (`barrierColor`) is already `Colors.black54`

Comment: it's rather the `modalBackgroundColor` property that should be changed in this instance (if being presented modally).

Answer (score 8):

**Hello friend, today you're in luck.
If you want to change the color of a BottomSheet, add the following code in the theme used by MaterialApp of the Main method.**

**I suggest you change this canvas color in a ThemeData widget that wraps the fab**

*As you will see the color of the canvas is who handles what you are looking for*

```
  ThemeData _baseTheme = ThemeData(
   fontFamily: "Roboto",
   canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
  );

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget
  {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return new MaterialApp(
  routes: myRoutes(),
  initialRoute: '/',
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: _baseTheme,
  title: 'My awesome app!',
 );

 }
}
```

Comment: The OP said "changing the canvasColor in the materialApp would do the trick, **but other widgets would also change colors**"... meaning it is not an option because he had already used the original color throughout the app.

Answer (score 6):

use backgroundColor property to change the color. 
To change the shape use shape property of showModalBottomSheet or apply shape_of_view container to manage shape.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        elevation: 0,
        context: context,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        builder: (BuildContext bc) {
          return ShapeOfView(
              shape: ArcShape(
                  direction: ArcDirection.Outside,
                  height: 20,
                  position: ArcPosition.Top),
              child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                      height:50

                    ),
                  )));
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

I use `surfaceTintColor` in Material 3.

```
bottomSheetTheme:
        const BottomSheetThemeData(surfaceTintColor: Colors.white))
```

Comment: This is the way, for some reason the `backgroundColor` of the BottomSheetTheme was not working properly, it was adding some kind of opacity. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Theme is not worked here.Widget rendered after background-color.You can set the  Container color to Colors.black54.

I don't think this is a good solution for this problem , but it works .

Sorry for my poor english!

This url will help you!
https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/5af4c5dfa52194a3f8577bf83af2e391

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put `backgroundColor: Colors.yourColor`
Example code is below

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    builder: (BuildContext bc){
      return Container(
        height: 430,
        child: BottomSheetWidget(name, test, images),
      );
    }
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by wrapping widget in a theme and changing canvas color and background color to transparent and filling a color in bottom sheet container. `

```
 GestureDetector(onTap: () => showModalBottomSheet(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext contxt) => Theme(
                                      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                                        canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
                                      ),
                                      child: Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                                topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                                                topLeft: Radius.circular(20))),
                                        height: 360,
                                        child: ChildWidgetOfBottomSheetYouWantToImplement.....
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by setting the bottomsheet theme of the app to this

```dart
bottomSheetTheme: const BottomSheetThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        modalElevation: 0
      ),
```

then giving the bottomsheet some margin

```dart
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (context) => Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 24),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24) +
            EdgeInsets.only(top: 36, bottom: 46),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: modalElevation: 0 is the key here