# Change gray overlay background of BottomSheet

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to change the overlay background color when using `showModalBottomSheet`?

Right now the color is always a gray color, but I want to use a different color like green as shown below.

[image: changing color]

Here is the code used in the demo for reference

```
        showModalBottomSheet<void>(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
              child: Text('This is the modal bottom sheet. Tap anywhere to dismiss.',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  fontSize: 24.0
                )
              )
            )
          );
        });
```

Comment: see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart#L270

Comment: does anyone know if we can have a custom element instead of the overlay, write cancel in the grayed area for example

Answer (score 27, accepted):

New Flutter UPDATE allows you to change the `barrierColor` in `showModalBottomSheet()`

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      barrierColor: Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.5),
```

Comment: Perfect! That makes it a lot easier

Comment: but, not change this status bar color.How this possible

Answer (score 4):

You can actually change this but in order to do so you have to create a copy of this widget file in order to customize it. (steps below are for vscode)

*However, by doing this, the widget won't be automatically updated by Flutter because it'd no longer be part of the SDK.*

**Create A Copy of A Widget To Customize**

1. Right-click widget and select `Go to definition` - *this will bring you to the widget's original file*
2. Copy all of the code and paste it into a new .dart file with the same name - *you'll notice there will now be errors due to a lack of dependencies.*
3. In the case of BottomSheet you just need to add `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`
4. Now import it like so `import 'package:projectname/bottom_sheet.dart' as my;` - *the `as my` allows it to use the same .dart file name*
5. Now when referencing it just add `my.` prior like so

```
my.showModalBottomSheet(
        context: (context),
        isScrollControlled: false,...
```

**Customize Background Overlay Color**

Now in `bottom_sheet.dart` just search for *barrierColor* and change `Colors.black54` to whatever color you want!

I hope this will help anyone in the future!

---

**Related Question**

[How to change the background color of BottomSheet in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204179/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-bottomsheet-in-flutter/51435590)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : you can't.

The color is hardcoded into the `_ModalBottomSheetRoute` class (as linked by @pskink) and there is no way to change its value.